# Increase efficiency for following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

Problem:-

```
input = n
output :-

1     2      3.......n [first row]
2n+1 2n+2   2n+3....3n [second row]

3n+1  3n+2   3n+3...4n [second last row]
n+1   n+2    n+3....2n [last row]
```

In the problem we have to print a square such that we have 'n' numbers of rows in our square and in every row we have 'n' numbers. We prepare rows from numbers from 1 to square(n) in such way we fill numbers for first row, then last row, second row, second last row and so on.....

for e.g. if `n = 4`
We start from 1 print upto 4 then print a newline, so our first row is:-

```
1 2 3 4
```

Then our last row comes in continuation

```
5 6 7 8
```

then our second row will be

```
9 10 11 12
```

few examples:

```
input = 1
output = 1

input = 2
output = 1 2
         3 4

input = 3
output = 1 2 3
         7 8 9
         4 5 6
```

My Code:

```
n = int(input().strip())
lines = [i for i in range (1, n + 1)]


line_order1 = []
line_order2 = []

#Reordering lines so we know the staring element of our method
for i in lines:
    if(i % 2 == 1):
        line_order1.append(i)
    else:
        line_order2.append(i)

 print(line_order1)
 print(line_order2)

 // Getting the desired order of lines
 line_order2.reverse()
 line_order1.extend(line_order2)
 print(line_order1)

 // Now printing the desired square 
 for l in line_order1:
     for i in range (1, n+1):
         k = n * (l - 1)
         print(k + i, end = " ")
     print("\n")
```

Is there a better way to do this in terms of execution time?

Comment: are you looking for speed of execution?  less code? more pythonic?

Comment: Please give more details. With your sample we cant understand 'the pattern'

Comment: In particular, why is `7 8 9` in the last example the second line?

Comment: "arrange rows of successive naturals in an n×n matrix such that diagonals and parallels thereof yield the same sum"?

Comment: Hi guys, i have updated the questions. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

While I see a few minor places you can improve your code, the performance is unlikely to be much better (my suggestions below might not make *any* performance difference at all). Your code will take `O(n**2)` time, which is the best you can do, since you need to print out that many numbers to form your square. Even if you combine some of your longer, more verbose steps into more compact versions, they'll can only possibly be better by a constant factor.

My first suggestion is to number the lines from `0` to `n-1` instead of from `1` to `n`. This will save you some effort when you have to calculate how what multiple of `n` to include in the values for the row. Currently you've got an awkward `l - 1` in your calculation that you could skip if you just used zero-indexed numbers for the rows. (Also `l` is a terrible variable name, since it looks like the digit `1` (one) in some fonts.)

My next suggestion is to simplify your code that builds the order. You don't need three lists, you can do the whole thing with one list that you feed two `range` objects, each counting up or down by two.

```
line_order = list(range(0, n, 2)) # count up by twos
line_order.extend(range(n - 1 - n%2, 0, -2)) # count down starting at either n-1 or n-2
```

Or, if you're willing to use a standard library module, you could `import itertools` and then use:

```
line_order = itertools.chain(range(0, n, 2), range(n - 1 - n%2, 0, -2))
```

The `itertools.chain` function returns an iterator that yields values from each of its iterable arguments as if they were concatenated together, without making any copies of the data or using significant extra memory. The difference is not likely to be a much here (since the maximum `n` you can usefully print out is fairly small), but if you were doing something different with the result of this algorithm and `n` was in the billions it would be very nice to avoid filling a list with that many values.

My last suggestion is to use a `range` again to generate all the numbers in each row directly, rather than explicitly looping from `1` to `n` and adding `k` each time.

```
for row_num in line_order:
    print(*range(n * row_num + 1, n * (rownum + 1) + 1))
```

You can compute the start and end points with the multiples of `n` already included, rather than needing to do that in a separate step for each one. You certainly didn't need to be recomputing `k` as often as you were before. You can pass all the values from the range to `print` in one go using iterable unpacking syntax (`*args`).

Note though that unpacking the range that way is sort of the reverse of the previous suggestion regarding `itertools.chain`. If `n` is large, using a loop over the `range` would be more memory efficient, since you won't need all `n` values to exist in memory at a the same time. Here's what that would look like:

```
for line_num in line_order:
    for value in range(n * row_num + 1, n * (rownum + 1) + 1):
        print(value, end=" ")
    print()
```